# How can I swap uppercase and lowercase alternatively?

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm writing a program that can convert uppercase into lowercase and lowercase into uppercase alternatively. Here are some examples.

> abcde -> aBcDe
>
> ABCDE -> aBcDe
>
> abCdE -> aBcDe

I know how to make it in c but not shell script. Here's the c code.

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <ctype.h>
  3 #include <stdlib.h>
  4 #include <string.h>
  5 
  6 int main(int args, char* argv[])
  7 {
  8 
  9     if(args != 2)
 10         exit(1);
 11     char buf[100];
 12     for(int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
 13     {
 14         if(i%2 == 0)
 15             buf[i] = tolower(argv[1][i]);
 16         else
 17             buf[i] = toupper(argv[1][i]);
 18     }
 19     printf("%s\n", buf);
 20 }
```

Can you guys help me how to write it in shell script?
Thank you.

Comment: It is a miracle that the C code works, when you did not terminate the string with `buf[i] = '\0';` after the loop.  But that would not have worked since `i` has gone out of scope and life.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to do this with a shell script when that comprehensible C code works perfectly fine (aside from the lack of null terminator and potential buffer overflow issue)? I'm of the opinion that a shell script would be a terrible tool for this. You might try `awk`, which should work on many systems and has a C-like syntax.

Comment: I'm with @ChronoKitsune: this isn't easy to do in a shell script, mainly because it is an exercise rather something that people actually need to do in practice. Does running a Perl program instead of C count as 'in a shell script'? What commands might you be allowed to use in your shell script?  Which shell are you planning to use? Maybe you use the built-in case-conversion facilities (or the `tr` command) to case-convert the argument to both lower-case and upper-case (in two separate variables) and then arrange to print characters alternately from the lower-case and upper-case variables.

Comment: Also, please note that it is not generally a good idea to include line numbers in the code (except for BASIC programs, perhaps).  They mean that people can't copy'n'paste your code and expect it to compile; they have to preprocess it first, which is a nuisance you shouldn't impose on people volunteering to help you.

Comment: Is any answer useful?

Answer (score 2):

With `sed` you can repeatedly parse 2 chars, changing the first in lowercase and the second in uppercase. That seems nice, but how about the last character with a string with an odd number of chars?
First change the last char to lowercase. That is OK for an odd length string, and will be modified with the second command for an even length string:

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
   exit 1
fi
lastcharlow=$(sed -r "s/(.)$/\l\1/" <<< "${1}")
sed -r "s/(.)(.)/\l\1\u\2/g" <<<"${lastcharlow}"
```

The last 2 lines can be combined:

```
sed -r "s/(.)$/\l\1/; s/(.)(.)/\l\1\u\2/g" <<<"${1}"
```

**EDIT: Text beneath**

The sed solution is nice and short, but doesn't show how to loop through a string. When you really don't know a tool working for you, you can loop through your string.
I will show 3 methods for changing the case of a char and two functions for looping through a string.

```
function upper {
   # tr '[:lower:]'  '[:upper:]' <<< $1
   # echo "${1^^}"                     
   typeset -u up; up="$1"; echo "${up}" 
}                                       

function lower {
   # tr '[:upper:]'  '[:lower:]' <<< $1
   # echo "${1,,}"                     
   typeset -l low; low="$1"; echo "${low}" 
}                                          

function grepsolution {
   i=0
   while read -r onechar; do
      (( i++ ))
      if [[ $((i%2)) = 0 ]] ; then
          printf "%s" $(upper "${onechar}" )
      else
          printf "%s" $(lower "${onechar}" )
      fi
   done < <(echo $1 | grep -o .)
   printf "\n"
}

function substr_solution {
   i=0
   while [ $i -lt ${#1} ]; do
      (( i++ ))
      if [[ $((i%2)) = 0 ]] ; then
          printf "%s" $(upper "${1:i-1:1}" )
      else
          printf "%s" $(lower "${1:i-1:1}" )
      fi
   done
   printf "\n"
}

for teststring in abcde abcdef ABCDE ABCDEF; do
   echo "Converting ${teststring}"
   printf "%-20s: " "grepsolution"
   grepsolution "${teststring}"
   printf "%-20s: " "substr_solution"
   substr_solution "${teststring}"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

You didn't say what shell you want to use. Depending on the shell, this can be complicated or easy.

For example, in Zsh, it is very easy:

```
myvar="abcd"
myvar_uppercase=${(U)myvar}
```

Comment: This uppercases all the letters. The question asks about alternating lowercase and uppercase in the output.

Comment: Oh, I should have read it more carefully. Of course in this case, my response is nonsense....