# I want to convert to lowercase any input I type in UPPERCASE, how to make this bash script section work using this sed command to lower any input

Tags: bash

I want to convert to lowercase any input I type in UPPERCASE, how to make this bash script section work using this sed command to lower any input?

```
selection=
until [ "$selection" = "0" ]; do
   echo -n "Enter selection: "
   sed 'y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/'
   read selection
   echo ""
case $selection in
```

Comment: `tr [A-Z] [a-z]` is a simpler way than that `sed` command.

Comment: Even easier, `echo -n "Enter selection: "; read selection; selection="${selection,,}"` (**note:** parameter expansion conversion to lowercase is bash-only "a bashism", if you need a POSIX portable solution, use `tr`)

Comment: I tried w/ tr it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks David C. Rankin, it works. Where is the place I should click to rate your answer as the best?.

Comment: You have to pipe the output of `echo "$selection"` through either `sed` or `tr` after you read it; you are simply intercepting the intended input with your `sed` command before `read` runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You intended to write something like

```
selection=
until [ "$selection" = "0" ]; do
   echo -n "Enter selection: "
   read selection
   selection=$(printf %s "$selection" | sed 'y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/')
   echo "$selection"
   case $selection in
```

Using a simpler `tr` command:

```
selection=$(printf %s "$selection" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')
# or tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

Using features available in `bash` 4 or later:

```
declare -u selection  # Convert any lowercase characters to uppercase upon assignment
until [[ $selection = 0 ]]; do
    read selection
    case $selection in
```

or

```
until [[ $selection = 0 ]]; do
    read selection
    selection=${selection^^}  # expand with lowercase to uppercase
    case $selection
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `typeset`.
Uppercase:

```
;-> typeset -u selection
;-> selection="UP and down"
;-> echo "${selection}"
UP AND DOWN
```

Lowercase:

```
;-> typeset -l selection
;-> selection="UP and down"
;-> echo "${selection}"
up and down
```

I wouldn't use `sed`. When you do want to use `sed`, you can use

```
sed -r "s/(.)/\l\1/g" <<< "${selection}" # Better use tr, typeset or ${selection,,}
```

Comment: Off topic: I liked my answer to a more complicated qUeStIoN : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41213411/3220113 which also shows different lowercasing techniques.

Comment: `typeset -u` and `-l` are Korn shell or `zsh` they are not supported in `bash` (which would prefer `declare` over `typeset` anyway).

Comment: `-u` and `-l` are supported by `bash` as of version 4.0.

Comment: Tx @chepner, I did not understand why it worked in my tests (with bash 4.0), hoping somebody would give some light.