# Changing alternative character from lower to upper and upper to low - Unix shell script

Tags: bash, unix

How to convert the alternative character of a string passed to script, if it is lower then it should be converted to upper and if it is upper then to lower??

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: When I pass the string to script then it should change the alternative character from lower to upper or upper to lower.

Comment: I still don't see a question. Hint: A question is a sentence which ends in a question mark.

Comment: Updated the question check out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
read -p " Enter string" str
for i in `seq 0 ${#str}`
do
#echo $i
rem=$(($i % 2 ))
if [ $rem -eq 0 ]
then
echo ${str:$i:1}
else
fr=${str:$i:1}
     if [[ "$fr" =~ [A-Z] ]]
     then
          echo ${str:$i:1} | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
     elif [[ "$fr" =~ [a-z] ]]
     then
          echo ${str:$i:1} | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
     else
echo ""
     fi
fi
done
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow you can modify your own question. Please add this code to the question instead of posting it as an answer.

Comment: Unless this is retagged as an advanced shell and not simple `shell`, then there are no string indexes and no `[[ .. ]]` in POSIX shell, e.g. `${str:$i:1}` (both are bashisms)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to swab every second characters case, try this:

```
read -p " Enter string " str
for i in `seq 0 ${#str}`; do
   rem=$(($i % 2 ))
   if [ $rem -eq 0 ]
   then
      printf "%s"  "${str:$i:1}"
   else
      fr=${str:$i:1}
      printf "%s" "$(tr '[:upper:][:lower:]' '[:lower:][:upper:]' <<<  "${str:$i:1}")"
   fi
done
echo
```

EDIT: Second solution
Switch case of str and merge the old and new string.

```
#!/bin/bash
str="part is lowercase & PART IS UPPERCASE"
str2=$(tr '[:upper:][:lower:]' '[:lower:][:upper:]' <<< "${str}")
str_chopped=$(sed -r 's/(.)./\1\n/g' <<< "${str}");
# Will have 1 additional char for odd length str
# str2_chopped_incorrect=$(sed -r 's/.(.)/\1\n/g' <<< "${str2}");
str2_chopped=$(fold -w2 <<< "${str2}" | sed -nr 's/.(.)/\1/p' );
paste -d '\n' <(echo "${str_chopped}") <(echo "${str2_chopped}") | tr -d '\n'; echo
```

Comment: No string indexes (`${str:$i:1}"`) in POSIX shell.

Comment: added another bash solution

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit challenging given that it is tagged `shell` and not as a question pertaining to an advanced shell like bash or zsh. In POSIX shell, you have no *string indexes*, no C-style `for` loop, and no `[[ .. ]]` operator to use character class pattern matching.

However, with a bit of awkward creativity, the old `expr` and POSIX string and arithmetic operations, and limiting your character strings to ASCII characters, you can iterate over a string changing *uppercase* to *lowercase* and *lowercase* and *uppercase* while leaving all other characters unchanged.

I wouldn't recommend the approach if you have an advanced shell available, but if you are limited to POSIX shell, as your question is tagged, it will work, but don't expect it to be super-fast...

```
#!/bin/sh

a=${1:-"This Is My 10TH String"}    ## input and output strings
b=
i=1                                 ## counter and string length
len=$(expr length "$a")

asciiA=$(printf "%d" "'A")          ## ASCII values for A,Z,a,z
asciiZ=$(printf "%d" "'Z")
asciia=$(printf "%d" "'a")
asciiz=$(printf "%d" "'z")

echo "input : $a"       ## output original string

while [ "$i" -le "$len" ]; do       ## loop over each character
    c=$(expr substr "$a" "$i" "1")  ## extract char from string
    asciic=$(printf "%d" "'$c")     ## convert to ASCII value
    ## check if asciic is [A-Za-z]
    if [ "$asciiA" -le "$asciic" -a "$asciic" -le "$asciiZ" ] ||
       [ "$asciia" -le "$asciic" -a "$asciic" -le "$asciiz" ]
    then    ## toggle the sign bit (bit-6)
        b="${b}$(printf "\x$(printf "%x" $((asciic ^ 1 << 5)))\n")" 
    else
        b="$b$c"        ## otherwise copy as is
    fi
    i=$(expr $i + 1)
done

echo "output: $b"       ## output resluting string
```

The case change is affected by relying on a simple bit-toggle of the case-bit (bit-6) in the ASCII value of each upper or lower case character to change it from lower to upper or vice-versa. (and note, you can exchange the `printf` and bit-shift for `tr` of `asciic` as an alternative)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sh togglecase.sh
input : This Is My 10TH String
output: tHIS iS mY 10th sTRING
```

Comment: After reading the answer that OP gave, I realized he did not want to toggle each character, but only every second character.

Comment: Oh, you did a better job interpreting than I did. I just got the "if it is lower, then upper, if it is upper then lower....", the "How to convert the alternative character of a string" is completely ambiguous to me on the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc... Interesting question - simply in C, not so simple in shell. Better, and faster, in advanced shell.

Comment: The C-code will look like https://stackoverflow.com/q/41211950/3220113 where I used `grep -o .` for reading 1 character (I could have used `IFS= read -r -n1 -d '' onechar`). Are these POSIX?

Comment: Good answer there. POSIX doesn't have `(( i++ ))` as a standalone, there isn't any `IFS` and of course no string indexes. The best references is [POSIX Shell & Utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html), though nearly all shells add something in addition to pure POSIX conformance. The POSIX spec is just supposed to provide a Least-Common-Denominator to insure portability. [ShellCheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) does a very good job pointing out POSIX issues.